# How to get node id in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am developing a drupal 7 module. And I have added two field "teaser" and "DOC" to custom content type.

When user create a node using that content type, he/she adds a DOC and save node. After saving node an image is created from the first page of doc(creating teaser for doc) and saved to a folder using ImageMagick lib.

And now I want node ids to link those images to node. So how I can get node ID.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should have used node_save($node) method to save the node. You can get the node id from the $node object by doing this:

$nid = $node->nid;